# How to mock Controller RouteData with MOQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq

My view has a file attachment as well as Captcha validation. The problem is I am using [MVCMockHelpers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) for my file validation but it reinitializes the route data (new RouteData()) while setting the controller context. My captcha validation always fails since it is trying to get the values from RouteData. Any help on how to mock route data  is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Raja

Answer (score 2):

```
var routes = new RouteCollection();
MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);

var mockedRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
mockedRequest.Setup(m => m.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/");

var mockedHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
mockedHttpContext.Setup(m => m.Request).Returns(mockedRequest.Object);

var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(c => c.RouteData).Returns(routes.GetRouteData(mockedHttpContext.Object));
controllerContext.Setup(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(mockedHttpContext.Object);
controllerContext.Setup(c => c.Controller).Returns(new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object);
```

I have something akin to this - I tend to wrap all these kinds of Mocks up in a helper and if necessary modify the setup from the test, such as changing the AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath or the route data.